# Pregunta formulario

Tags: javascript

Tengo varios formularios, que cuando se les hace submit, envian sus datos (:radio) a una función que se encarga de comprobar que todos los radios de ese formulario en cuestión estén seleccionados.

En la función, se le asigna a una variable cual es el formulario en cuestión (viene de una función que comprueba cual es la propagación del evento). 
Os dejo un fragmento de la función:

```
var validarRadios2 = function(data) {

    var formAValidar;

    if(data==1){
        formAValidar=elementosForm1;

    }else if(data==2){
        formAValidar=elementosForm2;

    }else if(data==3){
        formAValidar=elementosForm3;

    }else if(data==4){
        formAValidar=elementosForm4;

    }else{
        formAValidar=elementosForm5;

    }

    //var opciones = formAValidar.('radioButtons');
}
```

Mi pregunta es: En la última linea de código (que está mal, pero imagino que debe ser algo similar a eso), como puedo seleccionar los radio buttons de un formulario que ha sido guardado en una variable?!

Siento si es una pregunta simple, pero realmente no se como se hace y de verdad agradecería una ayuda.

Comment: estas asignando bien el formulario , algo como  `formAValidar = document.getElementById('elementosForm5')`

Comment: No, SOLO quiero asignar los radio buttons del formulario que está guardado en la variable.

Comment: ¿Usas Jquery o puro JS y ya tienes una forma de diferenciar los form? De cualquier forma creo que la cosa seria identificar cual de todos los form es el que dispara el evento, después de eso, verificas cual radio fue seleccionado o si los quieres todos entonces los input type radio que contenga dicho form. También deberías pensártelo porque la idea de los radio es solo seleccionar uno